# Comic where a man transported to an alien planet has to use an alien machine to return

Tags: story-identification, comics

Which specific comic from the 1960's had the story of a man from Earth who was suddenly transported to an alien planet where he found alien machines which he used to return himself to Earth?

In the story-line I recall, the planet was uninhabited and the man from Earth had to build a working transporter from long-abandoned alien machines.

Comment: Just machines, or a civilization?

Comment: In the storyline I recall, the alien planet was uninhabited and the man from earth had to build a working transporter from long abandoned alien machines.

Comment: Sounds like [Adam Strange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Strange)!

Comment: I would agree that Adam Strange appears to be the answer, except for the fact that in the storyline I remember the man was alone for a long time before he is finally able to build a machine that will transport him back to earth.  He never meets anyone on the alien planet.  I checked out the first issue about Adam Strange and he encounters a scientist on the planet Rann almost immediately.

Comment: It's hard to argue with that but I would just mention that the thing about these old comic characters, like Adam, is that they may have several different [origins](http://sequart.org/magazine/1744/your-guide-to-infinite-crisis-a-brief-history-of-adam-strange)

Answer (score 3):

Adam Strange, a character in the DC universe, was first published in 1958. He was an archeologist, who was hit by a "zeta beam" from the planet Rann, which transported him there. He learns to use the technology there, and becomes a protector of the planet. The beams wears off and returns him to Earth. But the scientists of the planet have provide him with the information to figure out where the next beams will hit the Earth allowing him to return.

[image]